# Outlook 2013 app deployment in production

Tags: deployment, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2013

Can a app developed for Outlook 2013 containing HTML, CSS and JS files (jQuery, Office.js) be deployed in a production environment by running an MSI?

I have read the resource available in MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142256(v=office.15).aspx

This resource talks about test deployment. However, I could not convince customer to follow the same approach as they are demanding an MSI file with COM add-in installation procedure in mind.

I want to confirm if I am overlooking any option available for production deployment.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't deploy Office Apps using MSI.